# How to compare lotteries, when one has higher probability of winning the jackpot, but another higher Expected Value?

Tags: lotteries

Table beneath shows that Pr(Keno's jackpot) > Pr(Grand's jackpot) > Pr(Lotto 6/49's jackpot). $\color{magenta}{\text{This Probability inequality tips you to buy Keno!}}$

But the Expected Value of 1

6/49 play $= \dfrac{$5E6}{13,983,816} - \$3 =  -\$2.64$.

Grand play  $= \dfrac{$7E6}{13,348,188} - \$3 =  -\$2.48$.

Keno play $= \dfrac{$2.5E6}{2,147,181} - \$10 =  -\$8.84$.

Hence, E(Keno) < E(6/49) < E(Grand) < 0. $\color{red}{\text{This Expected Value inequality tips you to buy Grand!}}$  Plainly, the outcomes from the $\color{magenta}{\text{Probability}}$ and $\color{red}{\text{Expected Value}}$ inequalities clash!

1. Intuitively, why does Keno have the  highest probability, but Grand  highest Expected Value? How do I intuit this contradictory information? Please unravel this cognitive dissonance that's freezing my brain!
2. Presuppose I can  live snugly on any one of these jackpots, and fancy winning whichever one. How ought I construe the above computations? How ought I decide which lottery to buy?

##### Data for 3 lotteries from the Ontario Lottery and Gaming Corporation

|  | [LOTTO 6/49](https://www.playsmart.ca/lottery-instant-games/lottery/odds) | [DAILY GRAND](https://www.playsmart.ca/lottery-instant-games/lottery/odds) | [DAILY KENO](https://www.playsmart.ca/lottery-instant-games/lottery-daily-games/odds/) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Jackpot** | \$5 million | <s>\$1,000/day for life</s> or \$7 million lump sum (I prefer lump sum.) | \$2.5 million |
| **Odds of winning jackpot** | $\dfrac1{13,983,816}$ | $\dfrac1{13,348,188}$ | $\dfrac1{2,147,181}$ |
| **Matching numbers required to win jackpot** | 6/6 | 5/5 + Grand Number | 10/20 on a \$10 bet |
| **Number pool** | 49 | 49 + Grand Number (7) | 70 |
| **Number of plays one person can buy** | [10](https://i.imgur.com/rmjU10P.jpg) | [5](https://i.imgur.com/5b5PMEM.jpg) | [2](https://i.imgur.com/h43DaJV.jpg) |
| **Price per play** | \$3 | \$3 | \$10 |

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_aversion

Comment: The same issues apply to financial investments: invest in an untried startup that could turn out the be the next Google, but will probably go out of business and leave you with nothing?  Or invest in U.S. Treasury securities that are nearly certain to pay 3.84% every year?   Bet your future on the one-in-a-million chance of becoming an NBA star or famous TV actor, knowing that most people who try do not succeed?  Or pursue a less lucrative career path that is more likely to end in a reliable income?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Such tradeoffs between higher probability of winning vs higher expected gain are found everywhere -- consider this toy example of a game that costs \$1 to play: you can win \$2 with 99% probability, or win \$980 with 1% probability. The expected values are 0.98 and 9.8 respectively, but people may prefer to play the first game because it's almost guaranteed to earn *something*. Compare this to investing in 1 index fund, vs hand-picking individual stocks that you think will do better. Something you may want to compute (if possible) is the [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance), where higher variance is generally more risky.
2. If you're only buying 1 ticket then I would maximize P(any win) because expected value is not terribly relevant for a one-off event. Since you are allowed multiple "plays" per ticket, your odds will become 10/13983816, 5/13348188, and 2/2147181, meaning P(Keno) > P(649) > P(Grand). Personally, I would not play any of these because they're all negative expected value.

Comment: Risk aversion can explain why it can be valuable to play gambling games even when they have negative expected value  Consider a fire insurance policy.  The cost to the subscriber is the insurance premiums. With high probability, they get nothing.  But if they have a catastrophic fire, then they ⸢win⸣ the bet and the insurer makes them whole.  The transaction certainly has negative expected value for the policy holder, as the insurance company works very hard to ensure that this is so. (If they don't, their business fails.)  But the decision to purchase the policy is quite rational.